# Does a system call involve a context switch or not?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls, interrupt

I am reading the wikipedia page on system calls and I cannot reconcile a few of the statements that are made there.

At the bottom, it says that "A system call does not generally require a context switch to another process; instead, it is executed in the context of whichever process invoked it."

Yet, at the top, it says that "[...] applications to request services via system calls, which are often initiated via interrupts. An interrupt [...] passes control to the kernel [and then] the kernel executes a specific set of instructions over which the calling program has no direct control".

It seems to me that if the interrupt "passes control to the kernel," that means that the kernel, which is "another process," is executing and therefore a context switch happened. Therefore, there seems to be a contradiction in the wikipedia page. Where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: syscall is a software interrupt. It changes to kernel mode and stack but still runs in the context of the calling process. The process pages are still mapped. No context switch is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong because the kernel isn't a separate process. The kernel is sitting in RAM in shared memory areas. Typically, it sits in the top half of the virtual address space.

When the kernel is invoked with a system call, it is not necessarily using an interrupt. On x86-64, it is invoked directly using a specific processor instruction (`syscall`). This instruction makes the processor jump to the address stored in a special register.

Syscalls don't necessarily involve a full context switch. They must involve a user mode to kernel mode context switch. Most often, kernels have a kernel stack per process. This stack is mostly unused and empty when no system call is active as it then makes no sense to have anything stored in it.

The registers also need to be saved since the kernel can use them. I don't know for other processors but x86-64 does have the TSS allowing for automated user mode to kernel mode stack switch. The registers still need to be saved manually.

In the end, there is actually a necessary partial context switch when entering the kernel through a system call but it doesn't involve switching the whole process. Since the temporary storage for swapped registers and the kernel stack are already reserved, it involves much less overhead as the kernel doesn't need to touch the page tables. Swapping page tables often involves cache managing and some cache flushing to make it consistent.

Comment: Great response, thank you.

To add: part of my confusion was that I was not clear on the sense in which we "pass control to the kernel."

In the Wikipedia article [1]: "the kernel executes a specific set of instructions" seems to imply there is some external "kernel" that executes the passive instructions (associated with the system call) that happen to be stored in kernel space. Arguably, it is the CPU that is executing those instructions (or perhaps the process within whose context those instructions are being executed).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Privileges

Comment: On most processor architectures, the page tables are the ones determining which portion of the virtual address space is priviledged and which isn't. The process has all its instructions and data in the lower half while the kernel is stored in the top half. On x86-64, when a process executes ```syscall```, the CPU jumps to the address specified in the STAR64 register, switches to kernel mode and swaps the user mode stack to the kernel stack using the TSS. At boot, it is the kernel's job to place an address in STAR64 to make the CPU jump to the proper instructions in the top half.

Comment: For example, on x86-64 Linux, the kernel places the address of the first instruction of entry_64.S (an assembly file). The assembly instructions there look at the RAX register for the syscall number and call other functions to do the main work. The kernel is shared between all processes by making the top half of the virtual address space global in the page tables. This makes sure that, when the CR3 register is changed, the TLB is not flushed for this portion. The kernel does have instructions but they are mostly interrupt handlers and syscall handlers.

Comment: The kernel isn't a process. It is instructions found in RAM at all times which can be called via interrupt or system call. Processes simply call those instructions with secure hardware mechanisms which vary between processor architectures.

Comment: @use123 *"On x86-64, it is invoked directly using a specific processor instruction (syscall)."* Naturally, there are many system calls that a process can invoke. How is it guaranteed that the one the current process needs is the one stored in that *one* register?

Comment: @Mehdi One CPU core executes only one thread at a time. Each OS uses different registers but, as mentioned above, the Linux kernel uses the RAX register. A compiler probably doesn't place the proper value in the RAX register along with the syscall instruction. Instead, someone else implements the standard library by compiling a shared library which contains the definition of these functions. Then, the dynamic loader makes sure to resolve the relocation left in your executable file that call in the standard library.

Comment: It remains that, at the end of the day, the code found in that shared library will most likely have some logic then eventually place the proper syscall number in RAX and execute ```syscall```. The kernel reads the syscall number in RAX and does the operation on behalf of the thread. The Linux kernel follows the System V standard for argument passing to syscalls and other things. It will be different on Windows.

Comment: @user123 *"the code found in that shared library will most likely have some logic then eventually place the proper syscall number in RAX*" Is this implemented in user mode, before `syscall` is executed?

Comment: @user123 Before the CPU jumps to the specified address in the relevant register, at least the value within the program counter would need to be saved so that the [running] process knows which instruction to execute next after the system call is finished executing. If that was the case, it looks as if this saving is done in user mode rather than kernel mode.

Comment: As stated on https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall.html: SYSCALL invokes an OS system-call handler at privilege level 0. It does so by loading RIP from the IA32_LSTAR MSR (after saving the address of the instruction following SYSCALL into RCX).

Comment: The RAX and executing syscall part is done in user mode. The RIP is saved in RCX by syscall. User mode has no control over that part.